# Subcategory of accessible category

Tags: category-theory, accessible-categories

For a full reflective subcategory $L$ of a locally presentable category $K$ one can state that $L$ is locally presentable.

Sure i do believe that a full reflective subcategory of an accessible one is not accessible in general but I would like to see a counterexample.

Are there sufficient hypothesis that force the subcategory to be accessible?

Comment: Don't you also need to assume $L$ is closed under sufficiently filtered colimits, in other words, accessibly embedded? In any case that one is true at least under Vopenka, so there can be no explicit counterexample. I don't know whether there is a counterexample in the accessible case.